# Theorem Bounding Minimum Supported Value Given An Expectation of a Discrete Random Variable

Tags: probability, convex-analysis, expected-value, convex-hulls

I have a discrete random variable $X$ and I know its expectation $\bar{X} = \mathbb{E}[X] \in \mathbb{R}$. I would like to say that the minimum of the support of $X$ must be $\leq \bar{X}$. Assuming this claim is correct, I couldn't see any problems with it, I would like to know if there's a general theorem out there I should be referencing when making this claim. Maybe something about $\bar{X}$ existing in the convex hull of the support of $X$?

Comment: What do you mean by “support of $X$”?

Comment: We have $P(X\leq E(X))>0$. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: If you know $\mathbb P(Z \ge 0)=1 \implies \mathbb E[Z] \ge 0$ then if $X \ge \mu$ you can find a $Y$ such that $\mu \lt Y \le X$ and $\mu < \mathbb E[Y]$.  Then let $Z=X-Y$

Comment: Thanks, I'm not asking for a proof. I just didn't know if there was a well known theorem establishing this. Like Cauchy-Schwarz inequality or the Jensen Inequality or the Central Limit Theorm (these are all wrong they are just examples of theorems I'd use in similar work).

Comment: @ W. Fan, I agree but is there a theorem "proving" it?